# how can I call Items from database in unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to develop a mobile application which uses Unity3d and Vuforia to create an AR app.

Is there a way to create a database in unity and by scanning an object, it will display windows with the content retrieved from the database?

For example, I have images and descriptions of food in price groups
and if I scan a bill, it will pop windows of the images in the database which belongs to the price group.

Comment: Sure you can, but you need to create online DB with some backend scripts to access DB via http. Like PHP script that 'echo' the response element from DB.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, is that the only way? i want to keep my app offline @JerrySwitalski

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to keep the app offline you'll have all your data stored locally on the device and can only update the data by updating the app.

If this is the way you want to go, the task is more or less straight forward. You can either:

- Keep all the data in files and load them from your Resources folder at runtime (Resources.Load) or
- Deliver a database engine with your app and use it to access a local database also delivered with your app

Depending on the complexity of your queries the second approach might (!) be more practical, however, database engines can be problematic because they may not be supported on all the platforms you may want to target.